# HTML center element inside div

Tags: html, css, alignment

I want two styled submit buttons (xx1 and xx2) to be centered inside their div (MainDiv). I've tried several things with no success. `margin: auto;` or `margin: 0 auto;` should do the trick. Does anybody know why following code is not centering inputs inside each MainDiv?

```css
.container{
    display:flex;
 align-items: center;
}

.MainDiv {
 height:25vh;
 background-color:transparent;
 width:50%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.SubmitGral {
 margin: 0 auto;
 height:90%;
 width:70%;
 border:none;
    background-color:#6c3;
 font-size:1.4em;
 white-space: normal;
 word-wrap: break-word;
    -o-transition: opacity .2s ease-in; 
    -moz-transition: opacity .2s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .2s ease-in; 
    transition: opacity .2s ease-in;  
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="MainDiv"><input name="Master" type="Submit" class="SubmitGral" value="XX1"></div>
 <div class="MainDiv"><input name="Master" type="Submit" class="SubmitGral" value="XX2"></div>
</div>
```

---

[fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/wg9mdor8/5/)

Comment: you want main div to be center in container or what?

Comment: Are you using flexbox for any particular reason?

Comment: Each input centered in div class="MainDiv"

Comment: check this one https://jsfiddle.net/wg9mdor8/7/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to add `text-align:center` to `.MainDiv` class and you are done.

See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wg9mdor8/8/)

```
.MainDiv {
    height:25vh;
    background-color:transparent;
    width:50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Leo the lion, Artem Solovev and UncaughtTypeError answers all solve my problem. I've been stuck here four hours, so thanks all of you! Mark this as accepted because can't mark all.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add `display: block` to `.SubmitGral`

https://jsfiddle.net/wg9mdor8/6/

```css
.container{
    display:flex;
 align-items: center;
}

.MainDiv {/*ok*/
 height:25vh;
 background-color:transparent;
 width:50%;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.SubmitGral {/*ok*/
 margin: 0 auto;
 height:90%;
 width:70%;
 border:none;
  background-color:#6c3;
 font-size:1.4em;
 white-space: normal;
 word-wrap: break-word;
    -o-transition: opacity .2s ease-in; 
    -moz-transition: opacity .2s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .2s ease-in; 
    transition: opacity .2s ease-in;  
    display: block;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
  <div class="MainDiv"><input name="Master" type="Submit" class="SubmitGral" value="XX1"></div>
  <div class="MainDiv"><input name="Master" type="Submit" class="SubmitGral" value="XX2"></div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do two steps:

- `.container { text-align: center; ... }`
- `.MainDiv { display: inline-block; ... }`

```css
.container{
display:flex;
text-align: center;
border: 1px solid black;
}

.MainDiv {
  display: inline-block;
height:25vh;
background-color:transparent;
width:50%;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.SubmitGral {
margin: 0 auto;
height:90%;
width:70%;
border:none;
background-color:#6c3;
font-size:1.4em;
white-space: normal;
word-wrap: break-word;
-o-transition: opacity .2s ease-in; 
-moz-transition: opacity .2s ease-in;
-webkit-transition: opacity .2s ease-in; 
transition: opacity .2s ease-in;    
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div class="MainDiv"><input name="Master" type="Submit" class="SubmitGral" value="XX1"></div>
<div class="MainDiv"><input name="Master" type="Submit" class="SubmitGral" value="XX2"></div>
</div>
```

---